# python script to get the apt-get update command history with date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, python, python3

I am writing a python script to get the apt-get command history with a date. Passing IP address and password as a parameter, then SSH into the host. In the command list, we have a list of Linux commands and execute these commands using for loop.  Is there any command to get the last linux update date? I tried  "history 5 | tail | grep 'apt-get update'" but python not able to print the output of this command.

```
import paramiko
import sys
hostname = sys.argv[1]
username = "root"
password = sys.argv[2]
commands = [
        "pwd",
        "history 5 | tail | grep 'apt-get update'",
        "ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp | awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'",
        "tail -n 25 /var/log/apt/history.log"
]
# initialize the SSH client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

# execute the commands
for command in commands:
    print("="*50, command, "="*50)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
del stdin, stdout, stderr
```

Comment: I just noticed that one of your commands pipes `ls -l` into `awk`.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) for why that's a terrible idea.   Use `stat` instead, it can give you a file's timestamp (or other metadata) without any need to parse ls - e.g. with GNU stat: `stat --printf='%y' /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp` (or use `%Y` instead of `%y` to get the seconds since epoch instead of a human-readable data, and use that with `date` to format it however you want).

Answer (score 1):

1. `bash` history generally doesn't record the timestamp of a command (and in my experience, setting the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable doesn't do anything useful).
2. You can check the timestamp of `/var/log/dpkg.log` (which is a quick way to find out the last time a package was installed/upgraded/removed) or examine the contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log` (which you can parse to get more details on exactly what actions were performed, and when).

e.g. the last two records from `/var/log/apt/history.log` on one of my systems are:

```
Start-Date: 2022-11-09  19:51:36
Commandline: apt -m -u dist-upgrade
Install: libjxl0.7:amd64 (0.7.0-5+b1, automatic), libhwy1:amd64 (1.0.2-4, automatic), libicu72:amd64 (72.1-2, automatic)
Upgrade: libvulkan1:amd64 (1.3.224.0-1, 1.3.231.1-1), libvulkan1:i386 (1.3.224.0-1, 1.3.231.1-1), libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), udev:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), source-highlight:amd64 (3.1.9-4.2, 3.1.9-4.2+b1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libglx-mesa0:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), systemd-container:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libpciaccess-dev:amd64 (0.17-1, 0.17-2), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), vulkan-tools:amd64 (1.3.224.0+dfsg1-1, 1.3.231.1+dfsg1-1), libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), libglib2.0-doc:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), pristine-tar:amd64 (1.49, 1.50), ffmpeg-doc:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libpam-systemd:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libboost-iostreams1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), libgbm1:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libgbm1:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libpciaccess0:amd64 (0.17-1, 0.17-2), libpciaccess0:i386 (0.17-1, 0.17-2), systemsettings:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), kwrited:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), liboxygenstyleconfig5-5:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libsystemd0:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libsystemd0:i386 (252-3, 252.1-1), libavdevice59:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), plasma-discover-common:amd64 (5.26.2-1, 5.26.3-1), ffmpeg:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), systemd-journal-remote:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), kde-style-oxygen-qt5:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libudev-dev:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libboost-filesystem1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), libboost-thread1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), kactivitymanagerd:amd64 (5.26.2-1, 5.26.3-1), systemd:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libudev1:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libudev1:i386 (252-3, 252.1-1), libpostproc56:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libosmesa6:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libosmesa6:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libboost-locale1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), libswscale-dev:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libboost-python1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), ksshaskpass:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libavcodec59:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libavutil57:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), liboxygenstyle5-5:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libswscale6:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libavogadro2-1:amd64 (1.97.0-2, 1.97.0-3), dh-elpa-helper:amd64 (2.0.14, 2.0.15), kmenuedit:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libicu-dev:amd64 (71.1-3, 72.1-2), libavutil-dev:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libglapi-mesa:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libboost-wave1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.74.1-1, 2.74.1-2), libboost-program-options1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), btrfs-progs:amd64 (6.0-1, 6.0.1-1), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libsystemd-shared:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libswresample4:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libboost-regex1.74.0:amd64 (1.74.0-17, 1.74.0-17+b1), mupdf:amd64 (1.20.3+ds1-1+b1, 1.21.0+ds1-1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (252-3, 252.1-1), libavformat59:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libegl-mesa0:i386 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), mupdf-tools:amd64 (1.20.3+ds1-1+b1, 1.21.0+ds1-1), dwarves:amd64 (1.24-2, 1.24-3), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (22.2.2-1, 22.2.3-1), libavcodec-dev:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), bluedevil:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3.1-1), pahole:amd64 (1.24-2, 1.24-3), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.113-2, 2.4.114-1), libkworkspace5-5:amd64 (4:5.26.2-1, 4:5.26.3-1), libsource-highlight4v5:amd64 (3.1.9-4.2, 3.1.9-4.2+b1), icu-devtools:amd64 (71.1-3, 72.1-2), libswresample-dev:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2), libavfilter8:amd64 (10:5.1.2-dmo1, 10:5.1.2-dmo2)
Remove: libflightcrew0v5:amd64 (0.9.3+dfsg-1+b4), libaqsis1:amd64 (1.8.2+git20210815-1+b1), flightcrew:amd64 (0.9.3+dfsg-1+b4), aqsis:amd64 (1.8.2+git20210815-1+b1)
End-Date: 2022-11-09  19:54:06

Start-Date: 2022-11-09  19:59:28
Commandline: apt-get -u install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
Install: linux-image-6.0.0-3-amd64:amd64 (6.0.7-1, automatic), linux-headers-6.0.0-3-amd64:amd64 (6.0.7-1, automatic), linux-headers-6.0.0-3-common:amd64 (6.0.7-1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-amd64:amd64 (6.0.6-2, 6.0.7-1), linux-image-amd64:amd64 (6.0.6-2, 6.0.7-1)
End-Date: 2022-11-09  20:07:29
```

These records are conveniently in "paragraph"-format (i.e. separated by a blank line) so can easily be processed with `awk -v RS=""` or `perl -00`.

---

NOTE: the apt history log only records things done by apt and friends.  It doesn't record anything done by `dpkg` alone.   The dpkg.log file, however, records anything done by dpkg itself **AND** anything done by apt/apt-get/aptitude or any other tool that ends up executing dpkg to install/upgrade/remove a package.

In other words, `dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` or `dpkg --purge packagename` will be recorded in `/var/log/dpkg.log`, but not in `/var/log/apt/history.log` (because it doesn't use `apt` at all).  `apt-get install package` or `apt purge package` will be recorded in both (because `apt` and `apt-get` both use `dpkg` to perform the install/remove/etc operation).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have `paramiko`, so I'll give an adjacent answer using `subprocess`: `subprocess.call("bash -i -c 'history -r; history'", shell=True)`. Or just scrape the bash history file by `cat`ting `~/.bash_history` or `~/.history`. `history` is a shell built-in and runs interactively unlike other executables found within the `PATH` and displays command execution history not timestamps. Rhetorical comment: this seems like something you can run with a shell script.

Some other links to research:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592827/how-to-add-a-command-to-the-bash-history-from-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745648/running-bash-script-from-within-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460923/run-bash-built-in-commands-in-python